# Is is possible to render a Webpart within another Webpart

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, office-fabric

I want to display a webpart within another webpart in Sharepoint Framework.

I am using Sharepoint Framework and have created two webparts. One of them fetches information about a user, the other one displays a GroupedList(office-ui fabric react). So far I looked for answers in the microsoft documentation but I wasn't able to integrate the UserData into the GroupedList

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

It's not possible to add a webpart into another webpart.

Do the webparts share a package i.e. are they in the same solution?
If so, I suggest creating 2 components for example:

- UserInformation (which retrieves the user information)
- ListView (which displays the groupedList)

The rendering of webpart 1 will return

`<UserInformation />`

The rendering of webpart 2 will return

`<ListView />`

When you want to combine the 2 into a single, third, webpart which renders for example:

```
<div>
   <h1>User Information</h1>
   <UserInformation />
   <h1>List</h1>
   <ListView />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This helped me to display the two seperate webparts.